# TeX-PDF-mode not working always in Emacs.

Tags: emacs, latex, auctex

I’m using Emacs (Aquamacs) on Mac for my LaTex files.

I always want to use LaTex (not Tex) and always produce a PDF file. 
The .emacs File contains

```
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)
```

besides some other stuff.

Usually everything works just fine, but some files are driving me crazy.

If I open them:

1. TeX-PDF-mode is not enabled and a “.dvi” file is created.
2. The View command opens TeXShop instead of Skim.

I don’t see any difference to other files, why is this happening?

```
\documentclass{article}   

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig,psfrag,mathrsfs,amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}

\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Keywords:}} #1}
%\providecommand{\preprint}[1]{{\small  #1}}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newcommand\preprint[1]{
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{\\#1}
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
  \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
\title{Some title}
\author{some one}
\date{January 29, 2014}
\maketitle 
\preprint{Preprint submitted to {\em  Journal of Scientific Computing}.}

\begin{abstract}
some text
\end{abstract}


\section{Introduction}
More text.\cite{article:BS2000}

\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\bibitem{article:BS2000}
No one.
\newblock foo foo.
\newblock {\em J.\ Comput.\ Phys.}.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

Comment: Use `(TeX-global-PDF-mode 1)` instead.

Comment: @thisirs Tried (TeX-global-PDF-mode 1)  already nothing changes.

Comment: The package `psfrag` is responsible for this. It triggers a style turning pdf-mode off...

Comment: @thisirs You are right, thank you!